# How to pass table name as a variable in QuasiQuoted Hasql query code?

Tags: postgresql, haskell

I am trying to write some generic Haskell code to insert rows into multiple Postgresql tables using the [`Hasql`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hasql-0.7.3.2/docs/Hasql.html) library.

I am not able to get a variable to substitute for the table name. Here is some sample code that illustrates the error:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes, ScopedTypeVariables, OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import           Data.Functor.Identity
import           Control.Exception

import qualified Data.Text             as T

import qualified Hasql.Postgres        as HP
import qualified Hasql                 as H

doit pool = do
  r <- H.session pool $ do
         let kName = "Rob" :: T.Text
             vValue = 34 :: Int
             tName = "t" :: String
         H.tx (Just (H.Serializable, (Just True))) $ do
           H.unitEx $
             [H.stmt| INSERT INTO $tName (name, age) VALUES (?, ?) |] kName vValue
  print r

main = do
  let
    dbConnStr = "dbname=testdb host=pg user=testuser password=password port=5432"
    pgSettings = HP.StringSettings dbConnStr
  poolSettings <- maybe (fail "Improper session settings") return $
                  H.poolSettings 8 30
  bracket (H.acquirePool pgSettings poolSettings :: IO (H.Pool HP.Postgres))
          H.releasePool
          (doit)
```

It compiles but there is a runtime error:

```
$ cabal exec runghc hasql-exp.hs 
Left (TxError (ErroneousResult "42601" "syntax error at or near \"$1\"" Nothing Nothing))
```

In the database log, the following error:

```
pg_1       | ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1" at character 13
pg_1       | STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO $1 (name, age) VALUES ($2, $3)
```

In the program, if I substitute `$tName` with just `t`, the query goes through fine. Does this mean that the table name cannot be loaded from a variable using the `Hasql` library?

Comment: Possibly out of context, but did you try `[H.stmt| INSERT INTO ? (name, age) VALUES (?, ?) |] tName kName vValue]`?

Comment: @EarlGray Yes, I did; it produces the exact same behaviour as with `$tName`.